# Line() Macro with Tuple

Tags: python, list, function, opencv, tuples

I am currently trying to do the following:

1. Create two empty list/array to hold one variable each
2. Use Moment() macro to generate colour detection center
3. Store coordinates achieved from Step 2 into empty list/array continuously
4. Convert list/array into tuple for line() macro
5. Use Line() macro to plot line on frame() macro

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)

point1 = []                                                                **-- Step 1**

point2 = []

while True:
     _,frame= cap.read()

     hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

     lower_red = np.array([0,50,120])
     upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])

     mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_red,upper_red)

     cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

     for c in cnts:
         area = cv2.contourArea(c)
         if area > 5000:


             cv2.drawContours(frame,[c],-1,(0,255,0), 3)

             M = cv2.moments(c)                                              **-- Step 2**

             cx = int(M["m10"]/ M["m00"])
             cy = int(M["m01"]/ M["m00"])
             point1.append(cx)                                               **-- Step 3**
             point2.append(cy)
             defconvert(point1):                                             **-- Step 4**
                 return tuple(point1)
             def convert(point2):
                 return tuple(point2)

             cv2.circle(frame,(cx,cy),7,(255,255,255),-1)
             cv2.putText(frame, "Red", (cx-20, cy-20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2.5, (255, 255, 255), 3)
             cv2.line(frame, tuple(point1), tuple(point2), (0, 255, 0), 3)   **-- Step 5**

     cv2.imshow("result",frame)

     k = cv2.waitKey(5)
     if k == 27:
         break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is a very crude breakdown as I didn't focus on the colour detection/contour codes but rather on list/tuple handling. However, when I executed the code below, it displays the error shown below:

`function takes 2 arguments, 1 given.`

[image: error]

May I check what I'm doing wrongly? Apologies if it's a rookie mistake, as I am extremely new to Python.

Comment: Hey Justin, this is an argument mismatch error, meaning you called a function with the wrong arguments - probably one of the points. Can you print their content in the line before the one that raises the error and tag me?

Comment: Hi @A.Abramov,


Thanks for the reply. This is what is printed out when I try it; displays (578,) (410,) for tuples point1 & point2 respectively.


https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sWNKpe_XtNGq9Uf1YW8XNaL59BG7VENa/view?usp=sharing


Best regards, 

Justin

Comment: I can't find cv2. You might want to debug this line by line and see which call exactly throws the error, since I can't understand why would the line highlighted through that error.

Comment: Is it perhaps due to the importing of cv2 library? Or am I interpreting "can't find cv2" wrongly? @A.Abramov